# Getting default environment variables

Tags: python, environment-variables

I have a code that operates in an environment that has been heavily modified since the program started. Is there any way to get an extra dictionary with default envvars?
By 'default' I mean env values that are available just after a program start.

One idea I have is that at program start I can:
1. deepcopy os.environ
2. encode this into some kind of long string (possible?)
3. save that string in os.environ['INITIAL_ENV']
4. later, restore from that string to any dictionary

It doesn't look like an elegant solution, but I could live with that.
Can you propose something? I need a solution for both linux and windows.

thanks !

Comment: I need to add a clarification:
The program is started with ALREADY modified environment - it's spawned with os.system() from another python script and thus inherits it's env, which is desired behaviour. I just need default ENVVARS as an extra data.

Comment: Does your program set environment variables with known names for use in subprocesses? Would namespacing (adding a custom prefix) to all the ones you set solve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, variable names are unknown before start and I can't rename them.
Actually I start to like the idea of serializing initial env to a big string, I just need to find out how to do that best !